# Making name badges for an event

Tags: civievent

I have a few Name Badge Formats entered in admin > system settings > option groups > name badge formats. One is a custom one that I've created and there are a few that were already there.

The Problem I'm having is that when I go to manage events and try to select a name badge format the select list has no options, I have no way of choosing anything. Is there something I need to do to enable these formats? If so, I'm not seeing that option anywhere.

Comment: Which version of civicrm are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to define your Name Badge formats at **Administer menu >> CiviEvent >> Event Name Badge Layouts** and not the "Option Groups" section.